# OpenVPN error in auth.conf

Tags: openvpn

Ubuntu server Jammy (22.04.1) new install, OpenVPN 2.5.5

client.conf has 'auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/auth.conf' and auth.conf has exactly two lines containing

```
username
password
```

It is not happy. syslog contains many entries (every 5 seconds or so) of the form

"vpn-auth[21744]: Options error: Unrecognized option or missing or extra parameter(s) in /etc/openvpn/auth.conf:1: username"

I've seen dozens of sites that refer to the 'missing or extra parameter...' part of this but none addressing the fact that the 'auth.conf' file needs to contain anything other than the 2 lines I've shown.

What am I missing?

Comment: I would assume you need to put your username and password in that file not the actual words.

Comment: @Rinzwind: of course that is true, but i'm certainly not going to put the actual username/password in this post. i'd have thought that would be obvious. however, according to the posts and OVPN docs i've read, there is no suggestion at all that OVPN "knows" what those words are other than first line is username, second line is password.

Answer (score 0):

I recently discovered why this occurs. There are two OVPN services on Ubuntu, openvpn.service and openvpn@client.service. If you're going to run an open vpn SERVER, use the former, if you're wanting to connect to another openvpn server, use the latter.